# Are there any services that offer 3D scanning?

Tags: 3d-design, 3d-models

So, have a plastic car part I want to duplicate because the driver side part is broken (I have the passenger side part) and It isn't sold anymore. It's a small piece that would be an excellent candidate for a 3D printed replacement. I know there are companies I can send a 3D model to that will happily print it for me, but I also need to create a 3D model from the part. Is there a company or service that I could mail the part to that would return it along with a 3D model of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=local%203d%20scanning%20services) (or other) search should do the trick. I've provided 3D Printing services via [3D Hubs](https://www.3dhubs.com/) and [MakeXYZ](https://www.makexyz.com/) and some people do provide 3D scanning services. If you can't find 3D Scanning, you could try talking to a local machine shop. They might have the tools to be able to reverse-engineer the object, or know another place that can.